# cannot reconfigure virtualbox-dkms

Tags: debian, software-installation, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, dkms

I have installed vitualbox on Debian Jessie according to instructions on [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/VirtualBox#Debian_.22Jessie.22_.28testing.29).
By running:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') virtualbox
```

During installation some errors were reported.
Now I want to re-configure virtualbox-dkms but I receive this error:

```
Loading new virtualbox-4.3.18 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.16-3-amd64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
```

Note: `uname -r` shows `3.16-3-amd64` but my source folder in /usr/src is named:
`linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64`.

I don't know what to do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did all of these solutions but problem was about my kernel!

linux-headers-`uname -r` wanted to install 3.16.0-3 headers due to my kernel version but there is no such linux kernel header in Debian repos: There is **3.16.0-4**

Solution: upgrade my kernel via apt-get then everything works fine.

Answer (score 13):

Run:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

If that second command still fails to find anything, then:

```
$ apt-cache search linux-headers-
```

to list all the `linux-headers` packages available.

At least one should match the kernel you are running (as displayed by `uname -r`).

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-<version number>
```

Comment: I still get this error, even with the headers installed using this command.